# MVC route with root URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

in my project I need to create two different front ends (Controllers, Views, js) that would use the same backend (Database, Service layer etc).
My first idea was to create a new area for one of the front ends but I do not want to use the /AreaName.

I want to register the routes in a way that if the user access 
http://site1.com, it uses a set of controllers and view from one area and if they access http://site2.com , it uses the controllers for the other area.

Also, it would be good if this can be configured on the same IIS web site.

Any ideas on how to do it? The main goal is to separate the code

Thanks!

Comment: you can configure two different domain names on the same IIS _server_ but not on the same _website_ within IIS, AFAIK. You'd have to create two separate websites. If it was me I would create two separate UI projects, which you can then deploy two the different sites in IIS. Obviously if there are some shared libraries / business logic you can create another project which both UIs can reference (or the trendy modern way would be to have a web API which provides that, and have quite a thin UI layer which talks to the API)

Comment: AFAIK, `IRouteConstraint` can be implemented to configure `HttpContext` with route matching constraint, depending on requested domain name, but require additional settings on IIS application pool. If you want to use different front-end projects, thus creating 2 web projects linked to shared back-end library is more preferred, or taking other way using Web API controller to process requests and provide responses for certain domain area.